# How to write a regexp in elastisearch so that it gives me URLs with numbers?

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to write a query in Kibana which works with Elastisearch Query DSL. The basic filter is as follows:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "path": {
        "query": "/abc/",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I need to write a query so that it gives me "path" which is of the form /abc/(0-9)/.

I tried the reference provided here but it does not make sense to me (I am not well versed with Elasticsearch):
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html

I would like to filter out results which are of the form path = /abc/12345/

Answer (score 1):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/ep97n3/1) might help you to do so:

```
\x22query\x22:\s\x22(\/.*)\x22
```

It creates a target capturing group, where your desired output is and you might be able to call it using <kbd>$1</kbd>.

[image]

You may add additional boundaries to your pattern, if you wish, such as [this RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/OZbU3k/1):

```
\x22query\x22:\s\x22([\/a-z0-9]+)\x22
```

[image]